# Правильно ли так говорить: "новогодний sale"?

Tags: лексика, вопрос, реклама

Увидела рекламный щит: "Новогодний sale". Хочу знать, правильно ли это? *Sale* на английском означает *распродажа*, женский род, а прил. *новогодний* стоит в мужском.

Answer (score 2):

Да, такая реклама встречается часто, например: **Новогодний SALE!** До Нового 2018 года осталось всего 11 дней! https://www.svyaznoy.ru/special-offers/3943094

Дело в том, что это слово читается как "сейл", поэтому в такой записи оно может относиться **только к мужскому роду.**

Сочетание "новогодняя sale" невозможно, оно не воспринимается на слух как нормативное.

Соответственно, **правильно: "новогодний sale".**

Кстати, слово переводится как продажа, распродажа (ж.р.), **сбыт (м.р.).**

Также:

**В орфографический словарь** слово ***сейл*** уже внесено.

**Викисловарь:** Существительное, неодушевлённое, **мужской род, 2-е склонение** (тип склонения 1a по классификации А. А. Зализняка).

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/сейл](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB)
https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/sale

Answer (score 0):

На определение рода влияет состав слова, а не то, как оно переводится на русский. Например, антураж (м. р.) переводится как окружение (ср. р.), а конкурс (м. р.) — как состязание (ср. р.).